# expected an indented block in python3

Tags: python-3.7

This is a code which is given to us by our teacher for using in our homework. There should't have been an error. But there is. Please help me fix it. (The error is in line9)

```
import socket

serverPort = 12000
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print ("The server is ready to receive")
while 1:
connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
byte_sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
utf_sentence = byte_sentence.decode("utf-8")
modified_utf_sentence = utf_sentence.upper()
modified_byte_sentence = bytes(modified_utf_sentence, "utf-8")
connectionSocket.send(modified_byte_sentence)
connectionSocket.close()
```

File "tcpserver.py", line 9
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
                   ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent your code by 4 spaces after you declare your while loop.

```
import socket

serverPort = 12000
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print ("The server is ready to receive")
while 1:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    byte_sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
    utf_sentence = byte_sentence.decode("utf-8")
    modified_utf_sentence = utf_sentence.upper()
    modified_byte_sentence = bytes(modified_utf_sentence, "utf-8")

connectionSocket.send(modified_byte_sentence)
connectionSocket.close()
```

everything in the while loop must be indented by 4 spaces. Returning to unindented code terminates the while looop.

Comment: I don't know what lines need to be in the while loop, I left the last two lines out. If the last two lines need to be in the while loop then they will need to be indented by 4 spaces also. Heres a good rule. Whenever you have to use a colon in python, the next line needs to be indented by 4 spaces. Returning the the previous indentation tells the interpreter that you have terminated the loop, class or def.